# Setting up my rails app to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am having trouble connecting my rails app to MySQL. I am using SQL Pro as my GUI.

Heres my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: ecommerce-app-development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: ecommerce-app-test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: ecommerce-app-production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I tried creating a database called 'ecommerece-app-developent' in SQL Pro, but heres the error message it gives me:

Connected to host, but unable to connect to database ecommerce-app-development.

Be sure that the database exists and that you have the necessary privileges.

MySQL said: Unknown database 'ecommerce-app-development'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the database before connecting to it. `rake db:create` will do this for you, then you can connect to it using SQL Pro or whatever.